# Table header Freezing along with iscroll and jquery tablesorter 2.0

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, iscroll

We have created an application with sorting table using jquery tablesorter 2.0 plugin 
The application has iscroll also included.

Now we need to freeze the thead and only the tbody should be scrolling .

please help me with some solution

we are using   the following code but its not working

$("table").tablesorter({

```
widthFixed : true,
showProcessing: true,

headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', 

widgets: [ 'uitheme', 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter' ],

widgetOptions: {


  stickyHeaders : 'tablesorter-stickyHeader',

  zebra   : ["ui-widget-content even", "ui-state-default odd"],


  uitheme : 'jui'

}
```

});

});

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using the original version of tablesorter? There are some other sticky header widgets available, but might I suggest you check out [this stickyHeaders widget demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sticky-header.html) which will only work properly with my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Mottie but We are also using  using   the following same code but its not working  $("table").tablesorter({

    widthFixed : true,
    showProcessing: true,

    headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', 

    widgets: [ 'uitheme', 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter' ],

    widgetOptions: {

      
      stickyHeaders : 'tablesorter-stickyHeader',

      zebra   : ["ui-widget-content even", "ui-state-default odd"],

      
      uitheme : 'jui'

    }

  });

});

Comment: Hmm, maybe check out this the [scroller widget demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html) then. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks Mottie .... I needed exactly Scoller widget demo as you shared. Header freezing is achieved. But i am unable to achieve table sorting in it. Please help me out and know what i am missing ?